# How to retrieve file with unicode name from Amazon S3 with fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, amazon-s3, fog

It works well with files with english symbols in name, but if file has cyrillic name, it fails with exception: "undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass"

```
@file_msg.file.retrieve_from_store!(File.basename(@file_msg.file.url))
@file_msg.file.cache_stored_file!
send_file(@file_msg.file_url,
          :disposition => 'attachment',
          :url_based_filename => false,
          :x_sendfile => true)
```

How i can retrieve file with non-unicode symbols in name from S3?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to **force_encode** the **File.basename**

```
@file_msg.file.retrieve_from_store! File.basename(@file_msg.file.url).force_encoding("UTF-8"))
```